# Sum of double exponentials with different patterns.

Tags: exponential-function, exponential-sum

Is there a formula for this expression without using sum? $$f(x) = \sum^x_{i=0}{2^i\cdot3^{i(i+1)/2}} = 2^0\cdot3^0 + 2^1\cdot3^1 + 2^2\cdot3^3+ 2^3\cdot3^6+ 2^4\cdot3^{10} + . . . + 2^x\cdot3^{x(x+1)/2}$$

Comment: As written, your summands do not depend on the index variable, $i$.  Hence we just have $f(x)=(x+1)2^x3^{x(x+1)/2}$.  Did you intend to have $i$ instead of $x$ in the summand?  If so, I don't expect there to be a simple closed form solution.  There isn't one for $\sum 2^{i^2}$ for instance.

Comment: Of course he meant $i$ instead of $x$ in the summation.

Comment: Oh yeah, sorry I just copied and pasted, forgot about the $i$.